# using header in netbeans C

Tags: c, netbeans, header

I tried to compile a simple C program with a header, a main, and another source file in `Netbeans` but it didn't work. I always get a huge error message.

I have absolutely no idea what I can do to make it work. Hope you guy can help me.

console:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/***/***/***/***/***/headertest'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:73: warning: overriding commands for target `build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/header.o'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:68: warning: ignoring old commands for target `build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/header.o'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/headertest
make[2]: Entering directory `//home/***/***/***/***/***/headertest'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:73: warning: overriding commands for target `build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/header.o'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:68: warning: ignoring old commands for target `build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/header.o'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/header.o.d"
gcc    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/header.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/header.o header.h
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d"
gcc    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.c
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
gcc     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/headertest build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/header.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/header.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o
/usr/bin/ld:build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/header.o: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/header.o:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/headertest] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/***/***/***/***/***/headertest'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/***/***/***/***/***/headertest'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 283ms)
```

Here is the rest of my code:
main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    lol();

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

header.c

```
#include "header.h"

void lol(){
    printf("lol");
}
```

header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define   HEADER_H
#ifdef   __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void lol();

#ifdef   __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif   /* HEADER_H */
```

Comment: Why are you compiling the header file?

Comment: According to log you're compiling header.h, while you should be compiling header.c

Comment: ok thank you. And how can i change what files will be compiled in netbeans ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not included `stdio.h`. Your `lol()` function doesn't know `printf()`.

Put a `#include <stdio.h>` either into `header.c` or `header.h`.